# Filtering Out unnecessary portions of scraped data

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to make a **scraper** that scrapes Post ID and Poster's ID from a Facebook public post link, using puppeteer and nodejs.

```
(async() => {
let url = 'https://m.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=1168301430177531&set=gm.1386874671702414'; //demo link
let brw = await puppeteer.launch();
let page = await brw.newPage();

await page.goto(url,{ waitUntil:'networkidle2'});

let data = await page.evaluate(()=>{

let ids = document.querySelector('div[class="_57-p"] > a[class="_57-s touchable"]').search; // for 
image post

return{
    ids
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

and I get output like:

```
{
 ids: '?fbid=1168301430177531&id=100009930549147&set=gm.1386874671702414&refid=13&__tn__=%2B%3E'
}
```

how can I filter out the unnecessary portions?(I just want fbid and id values)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is the most reliable and simple way:

```js
const href = document.querySelector('div[class="_57-p"] > a[class="_57-s touchable"]').href;

const searchParams = new URL(href).searchParams;

return {
  fbid: searchParams.get('fbid'),
  id: searchParams.get('id'),
};
```

Comment: Dude Thank you so much..... This was the perfect solution I was looking for <3

Answer (score 0):

Try use [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

it will help you to parse the query strings

```js
let search = '?foo=bar'
 
const parsed = queryString.parse(search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {foo: 'bar'}
```

it is just a simple example of what you should do

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with a regex like `/\Wfbid=(\w+)(\W|$)/`, the search result under **index 1** of the capturing groups will contain the desired parameter value.

```js
let ids = '?fbid=1168301430177531&id=100009930549147&set=gm.1386874671702414&refid=13&__tn__=%2B%3E'

const fbid = ids.match(/\Wfbid=(\w+)(\W|$)/)[1] // 1168301430177531
const id = ids.match(/\Wid=(\w+)(\W|$)/)[1] // 100009930549147
```

Without `[1]` you'd get all matches, e.g.:

```js
ids.match(/\Wid=(\w+)(\W|$)/)
```

=>

```
["&id=100009930549147&", "100009930549147", "&", index: 22, input: "?fbid=1168301430177531&id=100009930549147&set=gm.1386874671702414&refid=13&__tn__=%2B%3E", groups: undefined]
```

And you need the string between the capturing `&` characters, the 2nd element of the array (so: `[1]`).